# Splitting a String by number of delimiters

Tags: java, android, regex, string, split

I am trying to split a string into a string array, there might be number of combinations,
I tried:

```
String strExample = "A, B";
//possible option are:

1. A,B 
2. A, B
3. A , B
4. A ,B

String[] parts;
parts = strExample.split("/"); //Split the string but doesnt remove the space in between them so the 2 item in the string array is space and B ( B)
parts = strExample.split("/| ");
parts = strExample.split(",|\\s+");
```

Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Are you trying to split with comma enclosed with optional whitespace chars? `.split("\\s*,\\s*")`?

Comment: I want an array of the values, parts [0] = A parts[1] = B

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks it works

Comment: For a 5th option where input could look like `strExample = " A, B ";` use `trim().split("\\s*,\\s*")`

Comment: @Coder123 I [posted my answer, see below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53832041/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split with comma enclosed with optional whitespace chars you may use

```
s.split("\\s*,\\s*")
```

The `\s*,\s*` pattern matches

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `,` - a comma
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces

In case you want to make sure there are no leading/trailing spaces, consider `trim()`ming the string before splitting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
parts=strExample.split("\\s,\\s*");
```

for your case.

Comment: you need to add one `\\s*` before `,`

Comment: No,  I can not because I might have space before the comma, already got an answer in the comment below ^^, Thanks!

Comment: So you has space before comma, So `"\\s*,\\s*"

Comment: @Coder123 that comment was for the person who answered to make it proper.